# What is gap statistics?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering

For finding optimal number of clusters, one way that has been suggested is gap statistics. I have looked online but the articles are very math heavy and I am not able to make sense of it. If I could get a simple answer to it, that will really help.

Answer (score 0):

You generate random data and compare the quality of your clustering to results of clustering random data. If the result isn't better than clustering random data, the clustering probably did not work. But of course it is not sufficient to cluster randomly once, but you'll need many runs.

Comment: Thank you. Was looking for a simple answer like this :)